# Pass session as argument to user-function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

As I have to run the same part of code several times in my script, I was wondering if is possible to pass a `tf.Session` as argument to an user defined function in order to run some operations inside the function, thus avoiding the repetitive code.

**Update**
Example of use

```
with tf.Session as sess: 
        my_training(init, epochs, Xtrain, Ytrain, batch,\
                    optimizer, loss, predictions, X, Y, sess)
        validation_error = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X:Xvalid, Y:Yvalid})
```

where optimizer, loss, inputs, outputs, Xtrain and Ytrain, etc are previously created tensors, and `my_training` is the function I created to train the NN in a separate script.

```
def my_training(init, epochs, Xtrain, Ytrain, batch,\

             optimizer, loss, predictions, X, Y, sess):   

    # Shuffle the training set 
    Xtrain, Ytrain = shuffle(Xtrain, Ytrain, random_state = 20)

    # Initialize all variables (network weights, biases and optimizer)
    sess.run(init)

    # Loop over the training epochs
    for epoch in range(epochs):

        # Loop over mini-batches in the epoch
        for offset in range(0, Xtrain.shape[0], batch):

            batch_x = Xtrain[offset: offset + batch]

            batch_y = Ytrain[offset: offset + batch]

            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {X:batch_x, Y:batch_y})
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that, what is the programming issue? What did you try?

Comment: Hey @MatiasValdenegro. I just defined the tensors for a NN (inputs, outputs, loss, optimizers and placeholders), and, as I need to train it in different parts of my code, I was thinking to create a function that included all the training and then, from the main script just call it like in the update I included in the question.

So I could train and evaluate the model with just two lines of code. Seems to work, but I wanted to ask in case I was doing something dodgy.

Comment: What you are doing seems correct. There is nothing especial about passing a session as an argument, you only need to be careful to be sure that it is properly closed after use, but the context manager takes care of that (also, do not close the session within the function you are calling, or it will not be usable after). There are actually functions within TensorFlow that accept a session, like [`tf.Variable.load`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#load) or [`tf.Tensor.eval`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#eval).

Comment: Hey @jdehesa, I am not closing the session inside the function cause I want to use the optimizer trained by the function in my main script to compute the validation error, as you can see in the first part of the code I posted. Thanks for your comment.